# How can I get failed HTTP request body in java?

Tags: java, spring, http

I want to log all HTTP requests.

Normally, I can get a request body for a successful request with the code below.

But I don't get the request body if a request fails.

When I try to get the body of the failed request I only get an empty string.

How can I get failed HTTP request body in java?

-Filter class-

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class HttpLogFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String requestId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        response.addHeader(REQUEST_ID_PROPERTY_NAME, requestId);
        ThreadContext.put(REQUEST_ID_PROPERTY_NAME, requestId);

        ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);

        filterChain.doFilter(requestWrapper, responseWrapper);

        HttpLogDTO httpLog = collectHttpInfo(requestWrapper, responseWrapper);

        responseWrapper.copyBodyToResponse();

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        httpLog.setDuration(endTime - startTime);
        log.info(httpLog.toString());
    }

    private HttpLogDTO collectHttpInfo(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String scheme = request.getScheme();
        String host = request.getServerName();
        String port = String.valueOf(request.getLocalPort());
        String path = request.getServletPath();
        String parameters = request.getParameterMap().keySet().stream()
                .map(key -> key + "=" + request.getParameterMap().get(key)[0]).collect(Collectors.joining("&"));

        Map<String, List<String>> requestHeaders = Collections.list(request.getHeaderNames())
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        Function.identity(),
                        h -> Collections.list(request.getHeaders(h))
                ));

        Map<String, String> responseHeaders = response.getHeaderNames()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(h -> h, response::getHeader));

        return HttpLogDTO.builder()
                .protocol(request.getProtocol())
                .remote(request.getRemoteAddr())
                .method(request.getMethod())
                .uri(scheme + "://" + host + ":" + port + path + (StringUtils.isNotBlank(parameters) ? "?" + parameters : ""))
                .host(host)
                .path(path)
                .scheme(scheme)
                .port(port)
                .requestHeaders(requestHeaders.toString())
                .requestBody(new String(((ContentCachingRequestWrapper) request).getContentAsByteArray()))
                .statusCode(String.valueOf(response.getStatus()))
                .statusValue(Objects.requireNonNull(HttpStatus.resolve(response.getStatus())).getReasonPhrase())
                .responseHeaders(responseHeaders.toString())
                .responseBody(new String(((ContentCachingResponseWrapper) response).getContentAsByteArray()))
                .build();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SOLVED]**

The problem is not in the above Filter class.

The problem is that I did write the code like I don't expect body in the controller class.

Problem solved after adding my POJO class with @RequestBody annotation in the method.

**Old Code**

```
@PostMapping("/post")
public ResponseEntity post() {
    throw new BusinessValidationException(BusinessValidationRule.CITY_NOT_FOUND);
}
```

**New Code**

```
@PostMapping("/post")
public ResponseEntity post(@RequestBody Object body) {
    throw new BusinessValidationException(BusinessValidationRule.CITY_NOT_FOUND);
}
```